# Getting error: Prelude.(!!): index too large

Tags: list, haskell, indexing

I'm getting this 'program: Prelude.(!!): index too large' error for the following code:

```
select :: Field -> Field -> Table -> Table
select column_name column_value (header:t) = header:filterT t
                where filterT = filter testR
                      field_idx = (elemIndices column_name header)!!0
                      testR r | r!!field_idx == column_value = True
                      testR r | otherwise = False
```

I suppose the error is regarding the following part of the code:

```
              field_idx = (elemIndices column_name header)!!0
              testR r | r!!field_idx == column_value = True
```

Does anyone know why it's giving me this error or how I could fix it?

Comment: [1..10]!!11 returns the same error. It seems that you are trying to access an index beyond the capacity of r.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're doing, but I hope you're aware, that `!!` is not a safe operation. an element with the index doesn't necessarily exist.

So you could get this error, if, for example, the `header` doesn't contain `column_name`.

Again, not sure what you exactly want to do, but if there's a chance there's no result, perhaps you want to wrap the result with `Maybe`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not sure what Maybe does or how I could use it here?

Comment: it's simply `data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a`. So you either have a result (`Just the_value`), or you have nothing. So now it's going to be the client code's responsibility to figure out whether the operation succeeded (with, for example, pattern maching). This is one way to do error handling in Haskell, you might want to look up other alternatives. http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/03/10/haskell-8-ways-to-report-errors  Of course if the operation should always succeed, you don't need error handling, in that case, you have a bug in your code and you have to fix it ;)

Comment: Thank you! Will look into it certainly. Just I'm not sure how I should use a 'Maybe int' as index to retrieve the corresponding value of that found index (in another array that corresponds), as it will only accept regular Integers

Comment: You can get the int with pattern matching, the page I linked shows an example.